# Is the tense of my sentence correct?

Tags: american-english, past-tense

I have below sentence -

> I should have turned left at that point to leave the road behind and pick another road to reach Washington

I am little concerned on the the word 'pick'. Should it be 'picked'? Because, the theme of my sentence is based on some past event.

Comment: Both verbs there are governed by *to* and are infinitive. No changes to tense needed or wanted.

Comment: You are **a** little concerned, because if you were little concerned you wouldn’t care. That is why I think you should be asking questions on [ell.se] and not here.

Comment: “I have below sentence” is a matter of greater concern.

Comment: @Xanne could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: You might write: “The sentence I have written below . . . “

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you want pick to belong to "should have" or to "to".  You can parse your sentence in two ways:

I should have (turned left at that point to leave the road behind) and (pick*ed* another road to reach Washington)

or

I should have turned left at that point to (leave the road behind) and (pick another road to reach Washington).

You can clarify which you intend with a comma; for the first instance put the comma after *behind*, for the second put the comma after *point*.

Answer (score 0):

"I should have turned left at that point and picked another road to reach . . . "
Leaving the road behind is obvious (unless you must mention 'leaving it' for some reason)